# Spatial server metadata acquisition

Tags: metadata, server, request, services

I am trying to make a webpage which can post the possible requests and services from a spatial server, like geoserver can.

However I can only find owslib that can provide me the details. 
An example is:

```
[operation.name for operation in wfs11.operations]
```

that prints out

> ['GetCapabilities', 'DescribeFeatureType', 'GetFeature', 'GetGmlObject']

[from docs](https://geopython.github.io/OWSLib/)

another example I can think of is from the xml of a [geoserver-instance](https://arealinformation.miljoeportal.dk/gis/services/DAIdb/MapServer/WFSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WFS):

```
...geoserver/wfs?request=GetCapabilities"/>
```

where the request=getcapabilities are telling what services is supported. 
This can be compared to this example:

```
<ows:Operation name="GetCapabilities">
```

That states the [available services](https://arealinformation.miljoeportal.dk/gis/services/DAIdb/MapServer/WFSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WFS) in another way.

From the two latest examples I conclude that it would be a very large task to simply scrape the information from the xml, the task that owslib can do. 
I am restrained from using owslib in a web application because of webhotel restrictions, so I'm looking for another way of acquiring spatial server metadata.

Comment: This isn't really a GIS question, and I think you'd be better of asking at https://stackoverflow.com. As it is now, your question is really to broad to give a single answer, so maybe you could add some extra information about the techniques you are trying to use (JavaScript? Server side script? Something else?). Are the services you want to query on the same domain as the webpage?

Comment: You can use GeoNetwork to hold metadata about web services.